# Password_reset_done error when attempting to create reset password authentication

Tags: python, django, url

I want to allow the user to reset password when the user is signed out and cannot remember the password.

I am using the django authentication framework and have created the reset_password and password_reset_done mappers.

Issue : Though I have created the password_reset_done function I continue to get the below error.  Is there a step that I missed that is causing this error? I do not know what I have done wrong.

I have posted all the code that I think is relevant to what I attempting to do.

Edit with full TraceBack:

[image]

> Here is the code :

***relative urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_reset, password_reset_done


urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.vedic_view, name = 'vedic_home_view'),
        url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name' : 'exist/login.html'}, name = 'login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name' : 'exist/logout.html'}, name = 'logout'),
        url(r'^register/$', views.register_view, name = 'register'),
        url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name = 'view_profile'),
        url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name = 'edit_profile'),
        url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name = 'change_password'),


        url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, name = 'reset_password'),
        url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, name = 'password_reset_done')
]
```

***main urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin


from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] +  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


from django.conf.urls import include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView


urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^exist/', include('exist.urls', namespace = 'exist')),
        url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/exist/', permanent=True)),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`password_reset_done` is within the `exists` namespace. It looks like you are trying to `reverse` the named URL without including the namespace argument somewhere. We would need to see your full traceback to see exactly where that is happening.

Since you are using the built-in `auth` views, the easiest fix would probably be to move your password reset handling up to your main `urls.py`. Notice in your traceback that the built-in `password_reset` view does this:

```
post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_done')
```

The default implementation here is to `reverse` to `password_reset_done` without any namespace. Moving the relevant URLs up to your main `urls.py` will allow them to be accessed via `reverse` without a namespace argument, making the built-in views happy.

Comment: I have added the traceback

Comment: How would I move the password reset handling to my main `urls.py`?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, you are using the built-in views and templates for `password_reset` and `password_reset_done`. If that is the case, you can remove those two URL patterns from your relative `urls.py` and put them into your main `urls.py`, making sure to import both views from `django.contrib.auth.views` in your main `urls.py` as well. This will allow the built-in views & templates to call one another without worrying about namespacing.

Comment: Ok, I get you. As an aside I have no view function that will render the reset views, I just have the urls.

Comment: Technically you do have view functions that render those views, you just didn't write them yourself; you import them from `django.contrib.auth.views`. Here's the source if you're interested: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L210

Comment: lol. You are right, it was not manually created.Given that, would the view import still be needed in the main urls?

Comment: Yes, you will need to import into your main `urls.py` so that you can call them in your URL patterns there. More generally, anytime you define a Django URL pattern that calls a view (built-in or not), you need to import that view into your `urls.py` file somehow for it to work right.

Comment: @souldeux Is it possible to change the relative urls like this "url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, {''post_reset_redirect":reverse(''exist: password_reset_done")}, name = 'reset_password') " without moving these urls to main urls?. I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, you can pass several optional arguments to these views through the URL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

Answer (score 0):

I realize what the issue is.

For the built-in reset view there is a `post_reset_redirect` variable that uses the default implementation `reverse(password_reset_done)` to go to the password_reset_done view.

The issue is that in my main urls.py document I created the namespace variable

`namespace = exist`

However I did not override the default `post_reset_redirect` implementation
from `reverse(password_reset_done)` to `reverse(exist:password_reset_done)`.

So my current

> `url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, name = 'reset_password'),`

should now look like

> `url(r'^reset-password/$', { 'post_reset_redirect':
>   'exist:password_reset_done'}, password_reset, name =
>   'reset_password')`

Answer (score -1):

As I see, you didn't include `relative.url` in your main urls.

**EDIT**

in relative urls

```
app_name='exists' #with this name you can call in main urls
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.vedic_view, name = 'vedic_home_view'),
        #...
```

In main url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^exists/', include('exists.urls')),
    #...
```

**EDIT 2**

[Here'sthe docs on the subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls), it explains it better than me with examples.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Is the `url(r'^exist/', include('exist.urls', namespace = 'exist'))` not a reference to the target module?

Comment: like you added "exit" you need to add "relative":
`url(r'^relative/', include('relative.urls', namespace = 'relative')),`

Comment: Well it seems from the code you posted that relative urls are in a different file (inside an app) than main urls. If that's the case, you should inlude in your main url file `(projectname/urls.py)` and add the `app_name='your_app_name'` to call it, as you have called the `include('exist.url'...`

Comment: @guillermochamorro The name of the app is exist. So what would the syntax look like for you suggestion?

Comment: @WalthamWECAN I will edit my answer to show my approach.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I added the `app_name = 'exist'`. I am new to django so forgive my constant questions, but in adding the `app_name = 'exist' I am now able to call the main urls. How would I do that?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Here is a link to the repository if you are interested : [repository](https://github.com/iivri/exist)

Comment: Why the downvote? A correction or a reason for my answer would be appreciated. [I'm following the docs] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls).