# `registration/password_reset_email.html` not being rendered due to the absence of an custom exist template

Tags: python, django

I am attempting create the password_reset_confirm view for my application. However I keep getting this error :

This question is about the password_reset_confirm issue which was caused by the fact the the namespace `exist`  was preventing the default template `registration/password_reset_email.html` from being rendered, while the previous question is about the password_reset_done problem which was caused by the absence of the improved `post_reset_redirect` variable which accounted for the namespace `exist`

> Here is my code :

***app urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_reset, password_reset_done, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_confirm


urlpatterns = [


        url(r'^$', views.vedic_view, name = 'vedic_home_view'),
        url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name' : 'exist/login.html'}, name = 'login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name' : 'exist/logout.html'}, name = 'logout'),
        url(r'^register/$', views.register_view, name = 'register'),
        url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name = 'view_profile'),
        url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name = 'edit_profile'),
        url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name = 'change_password'),

        url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, { 'template_name' : 'exist/reset_password.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'exist:password_reset_done' }, name = 'reset_password'),


        url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done,  name = 'password_reset_done'),

        url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, {'post_reset_redirect': 'exist:password_reset_complete'}, name = 'password_reset_confirm')

]
```

It seems the namespace variable in the main urls.py is affecting the url mapping for the `password_reset_confirm`

***project urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin



from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] +  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


from django.conf.urls import include
from django.views.generic import RedirectView



urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^exist/', include('exist.urls', namespace = 'exist' )),
        url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/exist/', permanent=True)),
]
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the traceback as text, instead of posting images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct NoReverseMatch error with authentication algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058192/correct-noreversematch-error-with-authentication-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

The default `registration/password_reset_email.html'` includes:

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

This doesn't work, because you are using the `exist` namespace.

Removing the namespace from the include would be the simplest solution. If you must keep the namespace, then you need to create your own template that uses:

```
{% url 'exist:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

You have two options for getting Django to use your custom template. The first option is to use the default template name `registration/password_reset_email.html`, and make sure that the app containing the template is above `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

The other option is to choose your own template name (e.g. `exist/password_reset_email.html`), and specify `email_template_name` in your URL pattern:

```
    url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, { 'template_name' : 'exist/reset_password.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'exist:password_reset_done', 'email_template_name': 'exist/password_reset_email.html' }, name = 'reset_password'),
```

Comment: Is this the correct syntax : `url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, { 'template_name' : 'exist/reset_password_email.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'exist:password_reset_complete', 'email_template_name': 'exist/password_reset_email.html' }, name = 'password_reset_confirm')
`

Comment: No, that's incorrect. It's the `password_reset` view that is failing so that's the URL pattern that you have to change.